# How can I convert recursive types to JSON

Tags: .net, json

How can I convert an object that has recursive types (not objects, just types)? The following code fails when trying to serialize an object with a parent/child relationship.

The error is the last call to **ser.WriteObject(stream1, parent);** throws the exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233076
  Message=Type 'TestJson.Child' with data contract name 'Child:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestJson' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
  Source=System.Runtime.Serialization
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteArrayOfPersonToJson(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.WriteJsonValueCore(XmlWriterDelegator jsonWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson context, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteAdultToJson(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson , ClassDataContract , XmlDictionaryString[] )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonClassDataContract.WriteJsonValueCore(XmlWriterDelegator jsonWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson context, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
       at TestJson.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\src\TestJson\Program.cs:line 44
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The full code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace TestJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Adult parent = new Adult {name = "John", age = 42};

            MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Adult));
            ser.WriteObject(stream1, parent);

            stream1.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
            Console.Write("JSON form of Adult with no children: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());


            Child child = new Child { name = "Jane", age = 4, fingers=10 };

            stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Child));
            ser.WriteObject(stream1, child);

            stream1.Position = 0;
            sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
            Console.Write("JSON form of Child with no parent: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());


            // now connect the two
            parent.children.Add(child);

            stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Adult));
            ser.WriteObject(stream1, parent);

            stream1.Position = 0;
            sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
            Console.Write("JSON form of Adult with 1 child: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        internal string name;

        [DataMember]
        internal int age;
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Adult : Person
    {
        [DataMember] 
        internal List<Person> children = new List<Person>();
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Child : Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        internal int fingers;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it do exactly? How does it fail? What do you expect to happen and what exactly happens instead?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth There are no unknown types. The problem is the recursive types in the declaration.

Comment: @DavidThielen: Yes there are unknown types. Please see my answer and add any further comments there as I deleted my comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply follow the advice given in the exception message and add the `KnownType` attributes to `Person`:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Parent))]
[KnownType(typeof(Child))]
class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    internal string name;

    [DataMember]
    internal int age;
}
```

You need to actively make derived types known to the serialization engine via the `KnownType` attribute on the base class.
Your problem is not related *at all* to recursive objects.

Comment: Thank you - I had tried the KnownType on the Adult, not the Person.

Comment: Is there any way to have it not include "__type":"Child:#TestJson" in the properties? We have cases where we return several hundred of these on a REST get and that will add up.

Comment: @DavidThielen: I guess that would be a new question. In other words: I don't know ;-) However, the question is: How would the deserialization part know what type it is dealing with?

Comment: You just won my award for funniest comment of the month on S/O.